# Spring Boot register with JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am currently working on a Spring project, where I got the Security already implemented.(University) But I occurred the following problem: If I want to register a new user to the system, I logically do not have a JWT to authenticate the new user. I just get `Invalid authorization header or token` back from Spring, if I try to register a new user. So, I think the Security is not right configured:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserService userService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final RequestMatcher whiteListedRequests;
    private final SecurityProperties securityProperties;
    private final JwtTokenizer jwtTokenizer;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(UserService userService,
                          PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                          SecurityProperties securityProperties, JwtTokenizer jwtTokenizer) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.securityProperties = securityProperties;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.jwtTokenizer = jwtTokenizer;

        this.whiteListedRequests = new OrRequestMatcher(securityProperties.getWhiteList().stream()
            .map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }

   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
        http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1/users/sign-up")
            .permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
        http.addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), securityProperties, jwtTokenizer));
        http.addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), securityProperties));
}

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(whiteListedRequests);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final List<String> permitAll = Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        final List<String> permitMethods = List.of(HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name(), HttpMethod.PUT.name(),
            HttpMethod.PATCH.name(), HttpMethod.DELETE.name(), HttpMethod.OPTIONS.name(), HttpMethod.HEAD.name(),
            HttpMethod.TRACE.name());
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(permitAll);
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(permitAll);
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(permitMethods);
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Does anyone has a tip, how I can change the securityconfig, that a user can register himself against my Endpoint? (/api/v1/users/sign-up) I am kind of lost at this, and trying for several hours to manage the wanted behavior!
Thanks in Advance!

EDIT:

I just figured that my application.yml holds a whitelist:

```
security:
  auth:
    header: Authorization
    prefix: "Bearer "
    login-uri: /api/v1/authentication
    white-list:
      # Browser requests
      - /
      - /favicon.ico
      - /csrf
      - /v2/api-docs
      - /swagger-resources/**
      - /webjars/**
      - /swagger-ui.html
      # H2
      - /h2-console/**
      # Registration
      - /api/v1/registrations/
```

If I add the URI here, it works properly. But is there a solution to just add it via Code?

Comment: Could you elaborate on where exactly to add this whitelist in application.yml? The structure of my application.yml is `logging:` ... `spring:` ... `security:` ...
Under which category and where does it exactly belong?
And an off-topic question, you're not studying in Austria, are you?

Comment: @BenjyTec I updated my original post, showing the full yaml security specification (the relevant part). And yes I am studying in Austria, and we might have got the same non working template ;-) Good luck! (regarding antMatchers config etc.).

Answer (score 1):

the registration uri must not request a token, it must be allowed access from the outside.

it must be enabled at the antMatcher

Here is an exemple

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable();
        http.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/regitration/**")
            .permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
        http.addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(),userRepository,iLdapService,cryptoHelper));
        http.addFilterBefore(new JWTAutorizationFilter(),UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I changed my `void configure(HttpSecurity http)` in my origin post. Somehow, I still occur the same error.

Comment: Edit: I just found out, that my application.yml holds a whitelist. If I add the URI, it works properly.  But is there a solution just to manage that in the sourcecode?

Comment: would you please try to change the mthod order in the configure(HttpSecurity http) method, like i put it in the answer

Comment: I tried that out already (changed that in my origin post), but I still get an 401 back. It seems, its just possible through whitelist it in the application.yml

Comment: Would you please try to change the JWTAuthorozationfilter to the filter before !